# In Dagger2, what is the purpose of the @Singleton annotation?

Tags: android, singleton, dagger-2

Say we have a class `Counter`:

```
public class Counter {
    private int count;

    public Counter() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void count() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

And an `ApplicationModule` that provides the counter:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private Context context;
    private Counter counter;

    public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        counter = new Counter();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public Counter provideCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

By adding the `@Singleton` annotation to the `provideCounter()` method, are you specifying that only one Counter object will be provided?

In the event that we provide two `Counter` objects:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private Context context;
    private Counter numberOfTimesButtonAWasPressed;
    private Counter numberOfTimesButtonBWasPressed;

    public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        numberOfTimesButtonAWasPressed = new Counter();
        numberOfTimesButtonBWasPressed = new Counter();
    }

    @Provides @Named("buttonACounter")
    public Counter provideButtonACounter() {
        return numberOfTimesButtonAWasPressed;
    }

    @Provides @Named("buttonBCounter")
    public Counter provideButtonBCounter() {
        return numberOfTimesButtonBWasPressed;
    }
}
```

Would the `@Singleton` annotation be illegal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Singleton` will make sure that there is only *one of its kind* in the component.

So yes, setting it to singleton will result in the same object being used everywhere **this component** is used. If you create a second component, a second counter will also be created—it is a different object graph.

```
@Provides @Named("buttonBCounter")
public Counter provideButtonBCounter() {
    return numberOfTimesButtonBWasPressed;
}
```

This says, when I need a `Counter` named `buttonBCounter` call this method, **but** always the same objct will be returned because of your modules constructor:

```
// don't do this.
public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
    numberOfTimesButtonAWasPressed = new Counter();
    numberOfTimesButtonBWasPressed = new Counter();
}
```

Even though you did not annotate it with `@Singleton`, this method will *act* like it was, because you keep the object within your module and return the same instance on each call.

```
// do it right
@Singleton @Provides @Named("buttonBCounter")
public Counter provideButtonBCounter() {
    return new Counter();
}
```

This would have the same effect as the code above, although the method would only be invoked *once*, then dagger will handle the proper object caching.

Using dagger, it is probably a good idea to really let dagger take care of object creation.

You can then even go ahead and do things like...

```
// if you have an @Inject annotated constructor
@Singleton @Provides @Named("buttonBCounter")
public Counter provideButtonBCounter(Counter counter) {
    return counter;
}
```

...which will let you make full use of constructor injection. No need to update parameters if they change.

Also if in doubt, just add logging statements and/or attach a debugger. There is not much magic to it, go ahead and try it out!

Comment: Thank you so much! That clarified everything!